# how to merge data present in text files without changing the format using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 files, file1,file2 and file3, in file1 I have 3 columns say with 10 rows; in file2 I have 1 column with say 15 rows; in file3 I have again 1 column with say 10 rows. Now how do I merge all the files into one file without changing the format? I want columns of file1, followed by file2 and then file3.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code do what you need. I assume each element is separated by white space. This code works with irregular column length and there is no need to put 0 for empty elements in shorter columns. I tested it with simple examples.

```
def read_file(name):
    rows = open(name, 'r').readlines()
    data = []
    for r in rows:
        data.append(r.split())
    return data

def invert(data):
    new_data = []
    max_col = 0
    for r in data:
        if len(r) > max_col:
            max_col = len(r)
    col_no = max_col
    for i in range(col_no):
        cal = []
        for j in range(len(data)):
            if i in range(len(data[j])):
                cal.append(data[j][i])
            else:
                cal.append('   ')
        new_data.append(cal)
    return new_data

def merge(data_list):
    big_data = []
    for d in data_list:
        for c in d:
            big_data.append(c)
    return big_data

def write_result(result):
    result_file = open('result', 'w')
    for r in result:
        for e in r:
            result_file.write(e + ' ')
        result_file.write('\n')


data1 = read_file('file1')
data2 = read_file('file2')
data3 = read_file('file3')
new_data1 = invert(data1)
new_data2 = invert(data2)
new_data3 = invert(data3)
big_data = merge([new_data1, new_data2, new_data3])
result = invert(big_data)
write_result(result)
```

Comment: The hard part is handling columns with different part. In above code, the invert(big_data) handles that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it assuming your columns are space separated and the empty elements are zero

```
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2,\
        open('file3') as file3, open('output', 'w') as out_file:

    lf1 = in_file1.readline()
    lf2 = in_file2.readline()
    lf3 = in_file3.readline()

    line_f1 = lf1.strip() if lf1 else " 0 "
    line_f2 = lf2.strip() if lf2 else " 0 "
    line_f3 = lf3.strip() if lf3 else " 0 "

    while (len(lf1)!=0 and len(lf2)!=0 and len(lf3)!=0):

            print >> outfile line_f1, line_f2, line_f3

            lf1 = in_file1.readline()
            lf2 = in_file2.readline()
            lf3 = in_file3.readline()

            line_f1 = lf1.strip() if lf1 else " 0 "
            line_f2 = lf2.strip() if lf2 else " 0 "
            line_f3 = lf3.strip() if lf3 else " 0 "
```